# VBScript MS-Word Find & Replace Char for Addin Fields

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Okay, I've searched and searched and am hoping someone here can help me out.

I've been trying to get a VBScript program to open a word document, search for a specific char and replace it with a Addin field (i.e. { SEQ @ } )

Here's what I have thus far:

```
1     Const wdReplaceAll = 2
2     Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
3     objWord.Visible = True
4     
5     Set ObjDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\path\to\.doc")
6     Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
7    
8     objSelection.Find.Text = "@"
9     objSelection.Find.Forward = True
10    objSelection.MatchWholeWord = True
11   
12    objSelection.Find.Replace.Text = "replacement text"
13   
14    objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
```

This code works for "Find/Replace" but does not work for fields.

Much help would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Replace` replaces text, but you want to add a field. That's an entirely different thing. I'd suggest to `Find` the search text (leaves the text selected) and then `Add` the field (replaces the selected text):

```
With objWord.Selection
  .Find.Text = "@"
  .Find.Forward = True
  .Find.MatchWholeWord = True
  .Find.Execute

  .Fields.Add .Range, -1, "SEQ @", True
End With
```

To replace all occurrences of the search string you have to create a loop that keeps executing `.Find.Execute` until no further occurrences are found. The return value of the `Execute` method indicates if another match was found.

```
With objWord.Selection
  .Find.Text = "@"
  .Find.Forward = True
  .Find.MatchWholeWord = True

  Do
    found = .Find.Execute
    If found Then .Fields.Add .Range, -1, "SEQ @", True
  Loop While found
End With
```

Make sure your cursor is positioned at the beginning of the document before you run the above code, otherwise you might miss occurrences of your search text.

Comment: Okay, that works, but works for the first one. And with the `objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll` 
it takes all of them, replaces the first and removes the rest as blank.

Comment: Didn't I already explain that you cannot replace **text** with a **field** that way? I updated my answer with additional explanation and sample code.

Comment: Ah, yes/ Did not see that as a possible thing/ Thanks/ Accepted/